# Annotate a plot using matplotlib - showing values in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have two lists: one with strings in it (liste_string) and one list with numbers in it (liste_summe).
The list with the strings contains Date-Values as a string.
I want to show the values from liste_summe in the plot, but it doesn't work.

```
 plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=0.4, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)#Grösse des Fenster einrichten
plt.annotate(liste_summe, xy = (liste_summe, liste_datum))
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)#Schrägstellen der Beschriftung der x-Achse um x Grad
plt.ylim([y_min, y_max])
plt.plot(liste_string, liste_summe)
plt.show()
```

When I execute this code I get this Error:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Does any one has an idea?

Comment: In which line does the error occur? Remember when reporting about an error, include full traceback.

Comment: You need to show your data if you want help with this.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.annotate` cannot work with lists. As seen in [♠the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) it wants a string as its fist argument and a coordinate pair as it's second argument. Since the x value is the date, the first entry in the coordinate tuple must be the date (not the inverse). In order to annotate all points, you can use a loop; one call to `plt.annotate` per point to annotate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

liste_summe = [1,2,3,1,4]
liste_datum = ["2017-02-05", "2017-02-06", "2017-02-09", "2017-02-12", "2017-02-24"]
liste_string = liste_datum

plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
for s, d in zip(liste_summe, liste_datum):
    plt.annotate(d, xy = (d,s ))
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

plt.plot_date(liste_string, liste_summe)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If I execute your code I got this Error:File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 220, in _to_ordinalf
    base = float(dt.toordinal())

Comment: It might not work if your matplotlib version is 1.5 or below.

Comment: I have version 2.0

Comment: Ok, no idea what's wrong then. The problem is I cannot find alternatives and test them because for me this solution is already working. (using python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.0)

Comment: Now, since you do not provide your data in the question, chances are low to get another answer. Also, since the initial problem of the `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'` is solved by this answer, I might suggest the following: You may accept this answer and use the code from this answer in a new question, clearly stating that it is reported to work (linking to this question), but that you get an error on your system (include full info about system as well as the **full** error traceback). Posting this new question on a weekday may be more succesful.