# Annotations dont show (matplotlib graph with datetime data)

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

Im trying to make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146319/annotate-a-plot-using-matplotlib-showing-values-in-the-plot) work with my code, where each data point gets annotated.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1.5376248e+09, 48, 5682.47), (1.5376932e+09, 57, 5767.98), (1.5377112e+09, 57, 5767.98)])

time_test = a[:,0] # raw time data in unix time
x = a[:,1] # x coordinate
z = a[:,2] # text to annotate

date_1 = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)(time_test) # makes a datetimeobject from unix timestamp
date = np.vectorize(mdates.date2num)(date_1) # makes matplotlib date from datetime

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

for rsi, date_1, close in zip(x, time_test, z):        
    plt.annotate(close, xy = (date_1, rsi), xytext=(2, 2))

plt.ylim(40,70)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.plot(date, x)
plt.show()
```

I tried to copy the loop as closely as possible and now its at least error-free, but also the annotations don't show.

All ideas appreciated. Cheers

Comment: `xytext=(2, 2)` places all the texts at the same coordinate, namely at some point 2000 years ago and hence most probably outside the range of data you want to show.

Comment: aha, in the beginning I had only:
plt.annotate(close, xy = (date_1, rsi))
which results in "Image size of 1537711221x290 pixels is too large". So it makes sense what you say, but why isnt the default behavior that the annotation shows up directly on the xy coordinates?

and I played around with:

Comment: The default **is** to show the text at the `xy` coordinate, unless you specify `xytext` in which case the text is positionned at `xytext`. I think your problem is now that you use the "unix time" as positions on an axes which shows datetimes.

Comment: Got it now. It was a time format issue. I went back to unformatted timestamps and build everything back up. Thanks for your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
The updated code looks like this now:

a = np.array([(1.5376248e+09, 48, 5682.47), (1.5376932e+09, 57, 5767.98), (1.5377112e+09, 48, 56950.98)])

time_test = a[:,0] # raw time data in unix time
x = a[:,1] # x coordinate
z = a[:,2] # text to annotate

date_1 = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)(time_test) # makes a datetimeobject from unix timestamp
date = np.vectorize(mdates.date2num)(date_1) # makes matplotlib date from datetime

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

for rsi, date_2, close in zip(x, date, z):
     plt.annotate(close, xy = (date_2, rsi))

plt.ylim(40,65)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.plot(date, x)
plt.show()
```